# jhipster-entity-audit issue SQLSTATE(08003)

Tags: jhipster

I generated demo project from scratch. The project compiled and start with no errors and warns.

But after applying **jhipster-entity-audit** i'm seeing exception:

```
2018-01-17 03:46:54.194  WARN 128655 --- [demo-Executor-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@409be93d marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0)

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed(PgConnection.java:803)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.getAutoCommit(PgConnection.java:764)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.getAutoCommit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:336)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.rollback(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1166)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:205)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:170)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:196)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:94)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:77)
    at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When applying jhipster-entity-audit I selected:

`Custom JHipster auditing (works with SQL)`

**JHipster version: 4.13.3**

**.yo-rc.json:**

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
      "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.13.3",
    "baseName": "demo",
    "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
    "packageFolder": "com/mycompany/myapp",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "58737acdea1188e4cf1654fcec9e216448299e87",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en"
    ]
  },
  "generator-jhipster-entity-audit": {
    "auditFramework": "custom"
  }
}
```

**Entity configuration(s):**
no entityName.json file

**Browsers and Operating System:**
Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia

```
npm -v
5.6.0
node -v
v8.9.4
```

Please advice find workaround this issue.

Updated: I opened issue: https://github.com/hipster-labs/generator-jhipster-entity-audit/issues/82

**workaround:**
tip from @deepu105 for workaround just add string

```
cm.createCache(com.mycompany.myapp.domain.EntityAuditEvent.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
```

to *CacheConfiguration.java* file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I used IntelliJ for running dev. server.
I don't know why but i resolved it whith this step :

1. build manually with maven for test if it's an intelliJ bug (for me build is OK) : 
   `./mvnw`
2. got to intellij and open maven pannel : "view" --> "tools windows" --> "maven project"
3. On "profiles" menu active and desactive and active (again) "IDE" profile (for me "dev" profile is active too)
4. Now, try to build with intellij.

good luck

Comment: I tried to run by .`/mvnw` and by intellij idea with/without DEV profile - same error SQLSTATE(08003).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
And I realized that because of my dicision using OAuth2.
And I created new jhipster project using HTTP Session Authentication and run project again.
It's OK. Good luck